# can LessThanOrEqualTo from Foolproof validate int?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foolproof-validation

I try to use LessThanOrEqualTo from [Foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) version 0.9.4518 compare and validate int from another property, and it is not working.

however, it works for datetime format just like the example.

Here is my code:

model:

```
public partial class TryFoolProof {
    public int max { get; set;}

    [LessThanOrEqualTo("max")]
    public int? min{ get; set; }
}
```

I have the script file included in the view:(somehow, NuGet didnt include)

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MvcFoolproofValidation.min.js"></script>
```

here is the error:

```
mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMethod' of undefined
    at mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min.js:1
    at mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min.js:1
MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMethod' of undefined
    at MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.min.js:1
MvcFoolproofValidation.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined
    at MvcFoolproofValidation.min.js:1
```

so how can I get it work for int?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scripts needed for client side validation using foolproof are, in order

```
jquery-{version}.js
jquery.validate.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.js
```

and you need to delete `/MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.min.js` and `MvcFoolproofValidation.min.js`

In particular, you did not include `jquery.validate.js` so there is no validator to add the rules to.

Comment: I tried rearrange the order for the js file. still no luck :(.

The problem is LessThanOrEqualTo works for DateTime format, but for int.

Comment: It works fine. And you cannot change your original question and invalidate my answer and I have rolled back your changes (although you still had the `MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation` which needed to be deleted). I can only assume you did not follow the instructions or you have other mistakes as well, but the error message in the question is clear - _Cannot read property 'addMethod' of undefined_ is because the `$.validator` is `undefined` because you did not include the jquery.validate.js file.

Comment: Found the problem.
It was used wrong model attribute. after fix that everything works just fine.

Comment: That has nothing to do with your question which is about the error you were getting, and my answer is correct for your question!